# Como fazer pra reconhecer uma imagem no VSCODE em Python

Tags: python, pyautogui

### Problema

Estou aprendendo um pouco sobre o pyautogui e vi que da para usar a função **click()** para clicar em imagens, eu testei isso no Paint de diversas formas mas sempre da o mesmo erro e não sei exatamente como conserta-lo, vou deixar um código simples e além disso uma imagem dos arquivos e dos erros que aparecem.

---

### Código

```
from pyautogui import *

keyDown('alt')
press('tab')
keyUp('alt')

click('imagem.png')
```

---

### Imagem

[image: A imagem que contém o caminho que em teoria esta certo]

---

### Erro

> [ WARN:0@0.540] global D:\a\opencv-python\opencv-python\opencv\modules\imgcodecs\src\loadsave.cpp (239) cv::findDecoder imread_('imagem.png'): can't open/read file: check file path/integrity
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "c:\Users\name\OneDrive\Documentos\Name\Faculdade\Paradigmas\Python\Curso\testeProcuraImagem.py", line 7, in 
> click('imagem.png')
> File "C:\Users\name\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\pyautogui_*init*_.py", line 598, in wrapper
> returnVal = wrappedFunction(*args, **kwargs)
> File "C:\Users\name\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\pyautogui_*init*_.py", line 980, in click
> x, y = *normalizeXYArgs(x, y)
> File "C:\Users\name\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\pyautogui_*init**.py", line 661, in *normalizeXYArgs
> location = locateOnScreen(firstArg)
> File "C:\Users\name\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\pyautogui_*init**.py", line 175, in wrapper
> return wrappedFunction(*args, **kwargs)
> File "C:\Users\name\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\pyautogui_*init*_.py", line 213, in locateOnScreen
> return pyscreeze.locateOnScreen(*args, **kwargs)
> File "C:\Users\name\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\pyscreeze_*init*_.py", line 373, in locateOnScreen
> retVal = locate(image, screenshotIm, **kwargs)
> File "C:\Users\name\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\pyscreeze_*init*_.py", line 353, in locate
> points = tuple(locateAll(needleImage, haystackImage, **kwargs))
> File "C:\Users\name\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\pyscreeze_*init*_.py", line 207, in _locateAll_opencv
> needleImage = *load_cv2(needleImage, grayscale)
> File "C:\Users\name\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\pyscreeze_*init**.py", line 170, in _load_cv2
> raise IOError("Failed to read %s because file is missing, "
> OSError: Failed to read imagem.png because file is missing, has improper permissions, or is an unsupported or invalid format

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Comment: Você quer que o pyautogui clique em um arquivo específico na lista de arquivos do vscode? É essa a intenção? Não entendi bem o que está tentando fazer.

Comment: Eu quero que ele clique numa imagem, tipo, se aquela imagem estiver na tela, ele clique nela, no caso a imagem é um quadrado preto, então se tiver um quadrado preto é pra ele clicar em cima do quadrado, mas tanto na função click() quanto na LocateOnScreen() não funcionam e dão o mesmo erro

Comment: O correto mesmo é o LocateOnScreen mesmo, o que você pode fazer é implementar mais condições para ele tentar encontrar mais fácil, como no exemplo da documentação.
pyautogui.locateOnScreen('someButton.png', region=(0,0, 300, 400)) #Assim você escolhe uma região para ele procurar o botão (caso o botão sempre apareça em um local pré determinado ou próximo), assim você pode conseguir ser mais assertivo.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Boa tarde amigo;

O que eu faço para detectar uma imagem na tela é o seguinte:

```
import pyautogui

imagem = 'imagem.png' #<- seta a imagem como uma variável#

local = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen(imagem,confidence=0.5) #<- seta o local onde está a imagem e da uma margem de erro de 50% para caso a imagem apareça um pouco desfocada ou em uma resolução diferente ainda seja possível encontrá-la(use a variável local para conseguir mover o mouse para ela após achada, segue abaixo:)#

pyautogui.moveTo(local) #<- move para o local onde foi achada a imagem (variável local)#
pyautogui.click() #<- da o click onde foi movido pela função acima#
```

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).